# SQL Server - options for indexing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have about 200+ tables in my database. Every table has two columns `IsDeleted` and `IsActive` with type `BIT` for logical deletes. In all queries I check whether a row is not deleted or not `IsDeleted = 0` and `IsActive = 1`.

My question is: how do I create my indexes for best performance?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to be more specific in your question so contributors are able to help you out. What do you mean by performance, you mean faster queries?! Is your question about designing your database or about how to query an already established DB? Do you have the option to change you tables schema? Are you trying to find what columns should be used for indexing? What are the other columns in your tables?

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the main scenarios for which [Filtered Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) were added.  In this scenario Filtered Indexes allow you to create indexes that don't include the deleted or inactive rows, making the indexes smaller and the queries faster.

The alternatives are to add the status columns to all the indexes as key columns or to use partitioning or a separate archive table.  And neither is as simple as Filtered Indexes.

Comment: Is there a chance SQL Server will support mechanism like [In-Database archiving](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/in-database-archiving-12cr1) in future releases?

Comment: Is this best solution for thoes type cases?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda so Row-Level Security + a hidden column.  There's always a chance such a feature would show up, especially if it's heavily adopted in Oracle.  It would start with a feedback request: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes, I also thought about emulating it with RLS. As for Azure feedback I have a technical question: how many votes is required that idea gets at least some status update(like considered/declined/....). For instance [Add support for here-strings i T-SQL](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/34385422-add-support-for-here-strings-i-t-sql) has 15 months and no feedback

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are useful when they are highly selective. There is additional overhead when indexes are added to the database. So if you have a million row table and the indexed column can only have one of the two values (IsActive or IsDeleted) then you might as well forget indexing that column because there is very little difference in the indexed search and a table scan.